# Recreate views based on parameters

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres 15 to recreate some views.

To sum it up: I have views that belong to my database, let's call them

- view_a
- view_b
- view_c

For some projects, those views will need to be different since they might be project specific but I still will need both variants in my database.

The end result in the database should look like:

- view_a
- view_b
- view_c
- project_view_a

I made a function that will let me recreate wanted views with a given prefix. It takes two input parameters.

- prefix: a text value that represents the prefix to be added to the names of the views
- view_pattern: a text value that represents the pattern of the views
  to be modified. The function will modify all views that match the
  pattern specified by this parameter.

Inside the function, a loop is used to iterate over all views in the database that match the given pattern and that have not already been modified with the given prefix. For each view, the function retrieves the view definition using the pg_get_viewdef function and then modifies the definition to add the prefix to the view name.

Finally, the modified view definition is executed using the EXECUTE statement to create the new view with the modified name and definition. If a view with the modified name already exists, it will be replaced with the new definition using the CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW statement.

Here's my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_project_views(prefix text, view_pattern text)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
  view_name TEXT;
  view_def TEXT;
BEGIN
  FOR view_name IN SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.views WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name LIKE (view_pattern || '%') AND table_name NOT LIKE (prefix || '_%') LOOP
    view_def := pg_get_viewdef(view_name, true);
    view_def := regexp_replace(view_def, '^CREATE VIEW ' || view_name, 'CREATE VIEW ' || prefix || '_' || view_name);
    EXECUTE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ' || prefix || '_' || view_name || ' AS ' || view_def;
  END LOOP;
END;
$function$
;
```

I then call it using `SELECT create_project_views('project', 'view');`

**What I'm trying to achieve**

The behavior I have should be the same, but what I would like my function to be able to do is to also recreate dependent views with the given prefix. Dependent views are views that are in the DDL of my original view.

Here's an example

A view I have would be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.test
AS SELECT *
   FROM v_firsttry;
```

After running my function, the expected output should be:

1. prefix_test
2. prefix_v_firsttry

Any ideas on how to implement that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`information_schema.view_table_usage`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-view-table-usage.html) system view: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/8DLN95qO)

```sql
create table t1(a int);
create table t2(b int);
create view v1 as select a,b from t1,t2;
create view v2 as select *,'something more' from v1;
select * from information_schema.view_table_usage where view_name='v2';
-- view_catalog | view_schema | view_name | table_catalog | table_schema | table_name
----------------+-------------+-----------+---------------+--------------+------------
-- test         | public      | v2        | test          | public       | v1
--(1 row)
```

It lists both table-on-view as well as view-on-view dependencies in `table_name` column. You can iterate through that, the same way.

As an addition, if your object names are long/unique enough, on *nix you can pipe [`pg_dump --schema-only`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html#PG-DUMP-OPTIONS) through [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Examples), back to [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) pointed at the same databse to create an renamed clone. successfully restored by themselves into a clean database.

```
test=# create table a_fairly_long_and_or_unique_table_name (a int);
CREATE TABLE
test=# select schemaname,tablename from pg_tables 
       where tablename in (
          'a_fairly_long_and_or_unique_table_or_view_name',
          'a_clone_of_that');

 schemaname |                   tablename
------------+------------------------------------------------
 public     | a_fairly_long_and_or_unique_table_or_view_name
(1 row)

test=# \q
pg_dump --host=localhost --username=user --dbname=test --schema-only \
   --table='public.a_fairly_long_and_or_unique_table_or_view_name' \
   |sed 's/a_fairly_long_and_or_unique_table_or_view_name/a_clone_of_that/g' \
   |psql -h localhost -U user -d test  
psql --host=localhost --username=user test 
test=# select schemaname,tablename from pg_tables 
       where tablename in (
          'a_fairly_long_and_or_unique_table_or_view_name',
          'a_clone_of_that');

 schemaname |                   tablename
------------+------------------------------------------------
 public     | a_fairly_long_and_or_unique_table_or_view_name
 public     | a_clone_of_that
(2 rows)
```

When objects you clone have features you would otherwise have to find yourself (constraints, triggers, comments, ownerships, etc.) it's handy that it finds and includes all of them in the dump for you. It's only an alternative to how you clone, not a solution to the whole problem as it doesn't offer options to cascade and include dependencies in the dump, hence the notes:

> When *(object specific option here)* is specified, `pg_dump` makes no attempt to dump any other database objects that the selected `(object)`(s) might depend upon. Therefore, there is no guarantee that the results of a specific-*(object)* dump can be successfully restored by themselves into a clean database.